# How do I set token Secret and consumer secret in OAuth?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

AT both these site they ask for token Secret and consumer secret:
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html
http://developer.netflix.com/resources/OAuthTest#instructions

How do I set them programmatically:

```
public void excecuteSigning(String targetURL){
            HttpRequestAdapter requestSig = new HttpRequestAdapter(new HttpGet("http://photos.example.net/photos"));
            HttpParameters requestparameters = new HttpParameters();
            OAuthMessageSigner signer = new HmacSha1MessageSigner();

requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, "dpf43f3p2l4k3l03");        
            requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "nnch734d00sl2jdk");
            requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_NONCE, "kllo9940pd9333jh");
            requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_TIMESTAMP, "1191242096");
            requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_SIGNATURE_METHOD, "HMAC-SHA1");
            requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_VERSION, "1.0");
            requestparameters.put("size", "original");
            requestparameters.put("file", "vacation.jpg");
            String OAUTH_SIG = signer.sign(requestSig, requestparameters);
            System.out.println(OAUTH_SIG);
}
```

///The above generates this signature:rYexRY70p6aDDWw0ox0SwERRK2w=

///The code below does not generate the correct signature

```
requestparameters.put("oauth_consumer_secret", "kd94hf93k423kf44");
            requestparameters.put(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OAuthMessageSigner signer = new HmacSha1MessageSigner();
     signer.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
     signer.setTokenSecret(tokenSecret);
```

Works as it should now and generates the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the full source code for your client. With the values you provided, the google oauth test link serves this signature -

```
OAuth realm="",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_consumer_key="dpf43f3p2l4k3l03",oauth_token="nnch734d00sl2jdk",oauth_timestamp="1191242096",oauth_nonce="kllo9940pd9333jh",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="tR3%2BTy81lMeYAr%2FFid0kMTYa%2FWM%3D"
```

What signature value does your client generate?

Comment: The above generates this signature:rYexRY70p6aDDWw0ox0SwERRK2w=

Comment: There is no OAuth.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET paramater, how would I add it?